# Why there is an error "Invalid Property Value" when i set a background image of svg

Tags: html, css, wordpress, svg

In this image i want to display the svg image to the `<section>` tag as background Image.
I converted the svg code with url-encoder.

I am developing a theme for wordpress

help me with this.
[see the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wohL4.png)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you have a issue with quotes. You are placing url encoded svg as an inline style and that looks like this: `style="background-image: url(encodedsvg)"`; The url inside url function should also be inside quotes. I suggest you do not do this inline but in a css file. Or try using single quote for the inner url function, like this: `style="background-image: url('encodedsvg')"`

Comment: i did but now in inspect it shows `background-image: url(;
}` without the end braces.

and also this error **Error: <svg> attribute height: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected length, "".** in console